# Ignoring Optional Parameter in CLI function

Tags: c++, shell, command-line, bitcoind

I am trying to interact with a c++ command line interface. In the documentation they show the definition

`listtransactions ( "account" count from includeWatchonly)`

All values in `()` are optional parameters. Calling list `listtransactions "AccountName" X` will give me the last X transactions from AccountName.

I would like to supply the parameter for `Count` but not for `Account`. The goal being to retrieve the last X transactions form ANY account. However this does not work and it seems that the cli is assuming the count I am passing in is the account name and returns no transactions.

I have tried supplying `*` for the first parameter but that does not work either.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This seems to be dependent on the design of the application. If it doesn't provide a way to wildcard the account, there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: You interact with it from C++ the same way you would do it if you were running the command by hand from the shell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about how to use some random application, not about programming.

Comment: Okay I should have rephrased my question. I meant to ask, are there any other common ways/practices to wildcard parameters in C++ CLI's. Additionally, I tagged this question bitcoind because this is a common command in tens of bitcoin forked wallets. So Its not some random application, I tagged it appropriately

Comment: If you use an unquoted wildcard in the command line, the shell will automatically expand it to the matching filenames. You have to quote it to pass it literally to the command.

Comment: My point in saying that it's a random application meant that it's not a **programming** application. You need to read the documentation of the application, and see how you tell it to look in all accounts. Then just do that from C++.

Comment: So by that you mean I should try  `listtransactions * count` and not `listtransactions "*" count`

Comment: That was it.. I needed to send the literal wild card down to c++... quoting the wild card did it. `listtransactions "*" count` gave me desired output.

Comment: Please do not add your solution to your question. Instead, you can answer the question by clicking the "Answer Question" button below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an unquoted wildcard the shell will expand that input before it reaches the calling application. I needed to send the wild card literal down to c++... quoting the wild card does that. `listtransactions "*" count` gave me desired output